# how to add function on button click in laravel

Tags: laravel, function, button, onclick, whatsapp

i was have my team who was working on my project and certainly some of the reason they quit from this project now am just facing an issue that is whatsapp function is not calling on button click even function are there in code i am not familiar with laravel so much just beginner knowledge i have of laravel...

so kindly please help me i will be really thank ful to you sir

hereis the code of button

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal">Back to first</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="whatsapp-btn">Whatsapp</button>
                            <button class="btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel</button>
                        </div>


**here is the function code**

// whatsapp btn
        $('#whatsapp-btn').on('click', function() {
            var message = '';
            $('.checkout-table tr').each(function(i, el) {
                var product = $(el).find('td:first-child').text();
                var qty = $(el).find('input').val();
                message += 'product=  ' + product + 'qty=  ' + qty + ' </br> ';
            })

            var order_type = $('#order_type').val();
            message += 'order type=  ' + order_type + '  ';
            message += '%0a name : ' + $('#name').val();
            message += '%0a email : ' + $('#email').val();
            message += '%0a phone : ' + $('#phone').val();
            message += '%0a instructions : ' + $('#instructions').val();
            var url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+827667306&text=' + message;
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        })
```

Comment: Hi have you checked the console log? any errors? Press F12 in Google Chrome

Comment: "whatsapp function is not calling on button click"  ==>> try to explain this a bit more. On button click it needs to... open a modal? What does it need to do?